# Adding additional type in DefinitelyTyped library

Tags: node.js, typescript, fork, package.json, definitelytyped

I have Forked DefinitelyTyped and made changes to the types of a library. . I would like to test them from my fork instead of the upstream". Updated my package.json my "devDependencies" with the appropriate target `"@types/google-spreadsheet": "github:NewCoderOnTheBlock/DefinitelyTyped#delete-move-rows"`, then I proceed to use the command "npm install" Finally when I start to run my program i am encountering this following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'google-spreadsheet'. 'c:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Documents/Projet/Discord/node_modules/google-spreadsheet/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/google-spreadsheet` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'google-spreadsheet';`ts(701
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this isn't working because the DefinitelyTyped repository has a build step, and you're not running the bot that generates the package declarations.

You should be able to copy `types/google-spreadsheet/index.d.ts` into your project and then wrap it in `declare module "google-spreadsheet" { ... }` to test your types locally.